# JS and HTML - cloneNode() isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, dom, clonenode

Below code is working as expected.

**CloneNode.js**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <body>
            <script src="../js/CloneNode.js">
            function myFunction(){
                var the_node = document.getElementById("myList").lastChild;
                var the_clone = the_node.cloneNode(true);
                document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(the_clone);
                }
            </script>
            <ul id="myList">
            <li>Good morning</li>
            <li>Hello</li></ul>
            <p>Click on the button to CloneNode()</p>
            <button onclick = "myFunction()">Copy it!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

It is working fine for below code also :

```
<ul id="myList"><li>Good morning</li>
<li>Hello</li></ul>
```

OR

```
<ul id="myList"><li>Good morning</li><li>Hello</li></ul>
```

But when I enter newline before `</ul>` in above HTML code, like below, I didn't get the output. Hence, no addition of `<li>` element on the webpage.

```
<ul id="myList">
<li>Good morning</li>
<li>Hello</li>
</ul>
```

How can indentation in HTML code affect the output? Or is there anything that I've missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Element.lastChild` returns `TextNode` nodes as well as `Element` nodes, the new line character is resolved as an empty `TextNode` when queried, so to make it work regardless, change

`var the_node = document.getElementById("myList").lastChild;`

to

`var the_node = document.getElementById("myList").lastElementChild;`

Answer (score 0):

`try to put all of these within the same function as a local variables of that function.

1. const new_item = getElementById(elementID) // element you want to clone.
2. const cln = new_Item.cloneNode(true);
3. getElementById(elementID).appendChild(cln) // that element to which you want to append a new clone.

// I declared and initialized 1 and 2 out of the function where 3 was present.`